# Cannot click/select cell row on UITableviewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, xcode7

I have found many answers to this question but I have no idea why my cells are not being selected and taking me to my next view when I click on them. I have created a segue from the cell to my new view controller and used this prepareforsegue code:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
            // pass data to next view
            let indexpath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
            var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : [Answer]
            var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = levelsArray.map( { $0.AnswersArray })
            ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]
            DestinationViewController.ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo
        }
    }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please also post the code of you didselectrow (from where you are performing your segue Load View)as form you title it looks like you have problem there .

Comment: Have you double checked that "Load View" is the value you have assigned to the segue identifier in the storyboard?  Set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue and double check segue.identifier